# Puppeteer Crawler - Error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: javascript, proxy, web-crawler, puppeteer

Currently I have my Puppeteer running with a Proxy on Heroku. Locally the proxy relay works totally fine. I however get the error Error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED. I've set all .env info in the Heroku config vars so they are all available.

Any idea how I can fix this error and resolve the issue?

I currently have

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: [
      "--proxy-server=https=myproxy:myproxyport",
      "--no-sandbox",
      '--disable-gpu',
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      ],
      timeout: 0,
      headless: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## page.authentication

The correct format for proxy-server argument is,

```
--proxy-server=HOSTNAME:PORT
```

If it's HTTPS proxy, you can pass the username and password using `page.authenticate` before even doing a navigation,

```
page.authenticate({username:'user', password:'password'});
```

Complete code would look like this,

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless:false,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors:true,
        args: ['--no-sandbox','--proxy-server=HOSTNAME:PORT']
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Authenticate Here 
  await page.authenticate({username:user, password:password});
  await page.goto('https://www.example.com/');
})();
```

## Proxy Chain

If somehow the authentication does not work using above method, you might want to handle the authentication somewhere else.

There are multiple packages to do that, one is `proxy-chain`, with this, you can take one proxy, and use it as new proxy server.

The [proxyChain.anonymizeProxy(proxyUrl)](https://github.com/apifytech/proxy-chain#anonymizeproxyproxyurl-callback) will take one proxy with username and password, create one new proxy which you can use on your script.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const proxyChain = require('proxy-chain');

(async() => {
    const oldProxyUrl = 'http://username:password@hostname:8000';
    const newProxyUrl = await proxyChain.anonymizeProxy(oldProxyUrl);

    // Prints something like "http://127.0.0.1:12345"
    console.log(newProxyUrl);

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: [`--proxy-server=${newProxyUrl}`],
    });

    // Do your magic here...
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.example.com');
})();
```

Comment: This answer was helpful for me to realize an issue I was having. With the "http://username:password@hostname:8000" format, make sure you do not have an "@" sign in your password. This was the reason I was seeing `ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED` in my case

Comment: Can I use proxy-chain npm package with AWS Lambda?